# Unity - change sprites to something that uses less memory

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites, mesh, memory-efficiency

I have a game that uses only silhuette textures, but they take up waay too much memory (360 MB overall and this is a mobile game) so I plan to avoid using sprites with `alpha punchouts` (1 bit alphas). From what I gathered, I could use an asset from Unity store like `SVG importer`, but I have no financial means to do so. So I plan to make low poly 3D (in fact 2D) planes that somewhat cover my textures. 
Now, I have a **lot of** sprites already. I saw that Unity can create a `2D mesh collider` around my sprites. Can I use that to create my meshes and then apply a single colour unlit material to them? How would it roughly effect memory usage as opposed to my generally 500x600 sprites? 
If I'm going in the wrong direction, is there a way to create `Shapes`, just like in `Photoshop or GIMP`?

Comment: Switching to meshes could be a big savings. You'd be paying effectively per corner of the silhouette perimeter, instead of per unit of area, and it will stay crisp as you scale or distort it. You can use a script to get perimeter points from a generated collider, ie. [PolygonCollider2D.GetPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PolygonCollider2D.GetPath.html), but turning this into a triangulated polygon is a fair bit of work and not guaranteed to have the density you want. You might get better results tracing your sprites into polygons manually, using 3D tools like Blender or Sketchup.

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks. I know it ain't easy to automate, but AFAIK Unity can create a collider for an alpha punchout sprite under one click. it isn't the smoothest collision but it would be fair enough. Is there a way to convert that collider to a Mesh? Or any automation in 3D apps? I can do it by hand but it would take forever.